# Overridden hashCode() function is not called by any of HashMap methods

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have overridden hashCode() and equals() method in my class `Supplier` given below.

```
public class Supplier {

private final String name;

public Supplier(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {        
    char[] charArray = name.toCharArray();
    int sumOfchars = 0;
    for (char element : charArray) {
        sumOfchars += element;
    }
    return 51 * sumOfchars;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {        
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Supplier other = (Supplier) o;
    return this.name.equals(other.name);
}
}
```

Objects of this class are added to a HashMap with `name` field as Key.

```
Supplier s1 = new Supplier("supplierA");
Supplier s2 = new Supplier("supplierB");
Map<String, Supplier> supplierMap = new HashMap<>();
supplierMap.put(s1.getName(), s1);
supplierMap.put(s2.getName(), s2);
supplierMap.containsKey("supplierA"));
```

But, when I `put()` or `get()` an element my overridden `hashCode()` method is not called. Same is the case for `equals()` when I use `contains(Key key)`. I thought `HashMap` internally calls `hashCode()` in case of `put` and `get()`. And `equals` is called in case of `contains()`. Kindly throw some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using java.lang.String value of 'name' as your key - hence the hashcode method on your object will not be called.

If you were to do Map<Supplier, Object> or something else then it would be called.

Comment: Thanks, on changing my code to  `Map<Supplier, String> supplierMap = new HashMap<>(10);` it does call my overridden `hashCode()` method. But in case of `contains()`, `hashCode()` is called but `equals()` is not. Any clue ?

Comment: equals will be called only if there is more than one object in the same bucket

Answer (score 7):

When you `put` something in a `HashMap`, the `hashCode()` method is called on the key, not the value.  So in this case, it's the `hashCode` from `String` that gets called on `s1.getName()` and `s2.getName()`.

Comment: You mean `hashCode()` from class `java.lang.String` is called, if Key is of type `String` ? What about the `equals()` method, is it also called from the `String` class. But if it is so, how can I impose `equals()` method as per my Object type. A bit confusing.

Comment: In this case, you're using the supplier's name as the key.  If you used something that isn't a `String`, you'd get some other `hashCode` method being called.